# IP Fragmentation - What if the last fragment arrives before other packets

Tags: networking, ip, ip-fragmentation

During reassembling of fragmented packets, I am putting the fragmented packets in a buffer. Before timeout reaches, I see if the last fragment has arrived, I will reassemble them and deliver to the upper layers.

Basic question is how will the reassembly take place if the last fragment arrives before other fragments.

Another doubt is what data structure would be better to use a fragment buffer? Will a hashmap with identification number as key help?

Comment: IP actually handles all that for you.

Comment: No actually I have to design the network stack. I have to implement it

Comment: You are building your own IP stack? All that is explained in the RFCs along with the algorithms.